# Why call a Base Class virtual member from an Inherited class?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I've done C++ stuff for a number of years, no formal training, though.  Most of my background is aerospace where we had to always reinvent the wheel, no use of 3rd party libraries or APIs, so those are kind of new to me.

I'm working on something that does have an API and I am a little confused by some existing code.  When asking co-workers, they don't have any answers, either.

I have a class that inherits the API's `Application` class. This `Application` class has a protected virtual function called `onUpdate()`, described as:

> Function Callback for updating logic, called every frame

```
class MyApp : public Application {
public:
   virtual void onUpdate() override;
}
void MyApp::onUpdate() {
   Application::onUpdate(); // Why do this?
...
}
```

First off, I thought that callbacks would have some sort of function pointer, lambda, something in them.

The only answer that someone mentioned was that this was a "typical" thing to do so that the `Application::onUpdate()` function, which might be different, would be called.  But doesn't declaring a virtual function override the base class implementation if there is one?

I would have thought that if this is necessary, the documentation would say something like "be sure to call the base class `onUpdate` function if you choose to write your own".

I've tried a break point at the call, it appears to do nothing.  I'm wondering if the compiler is optimizing it out, even thought I have `-O0`.  I can remove it and the code appears to run just fine, but it is quite complex, so I don't want to create some downstream issues.

I'm not even sure what to search on. I can't seem to find a similar example.  Is there a formal name for this implementation?  I'm having trouble wrapping my brain around this one.

Comment: Since you are deriving a new class from `Application`, presumably there is a way for you to register your class with the API so that it knows to actually use it.  Then presumably somewhere inside the API there is a call being made to `onUpdate()` via an `Application*` pointer that is pointing at an instance of your class, thus calling your overridden `onUpdate()` via virtual dispatch. That is the only way that overriding `onUpdate()` would make sense.

Comment: Presumably, the author of this code wanted to protect himself in case some functionality was ever added to `Application::onUpdate` that derived classes might need / benefit from.  It's an example of defensive programming, although, in this case, maybe not warranted.

Comment: There are no Application* pointers.  The derived class has several functions that are spawned off as threads that are kept alive with while loops and this_thread::sleep() functions.  This is all very strange to me.  The call stack when in the derived onUpdate function just says External Code, so I assume that the library code is hiding something.

Comment: I don't see any calls to register the class, and the API doesn't seem to provide any "register" functions.  I hate to say this, but it just "magically" works, which also bothers me quite a bit.

Comment: @brettgrant99 Is the `Application`'s `onUpdate` member function pure virtual? If not, the function still exits. Maybe there is some sort of complex initialization code that must be performed first before your code executes

Comment: Not sure if you're familiar with `C#` but it's in the same vein as calling `base.SomeMethod( )` in a method that was overridden in a derived class. I only bring up `C#` here because that is a pretty common pattern

Comment: @WBuck `Is the Application's onUpdate member function pure virtual? If not, the function still exits.` Also, even if the function is pure virtual, its definition may still exist  - and has to exist for the example program to be correct.

Comment: Apparantly this is the ["Call super"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_super) anti-pattern if calling `BaseClass::function()` is required when overriding `function`, but it looks like here it's optional.

Comment: @WBuck it is not a pure virtual function.

Comment: @brettgrant99 "*There are no Application* pointers.*" - the API has to be using a pointer/reference to a `MyApp` object, otherwise your code makes no sense. Virtual polymorphism doesn't work without a pointer/reference. "*The derived class has several functions ...*" - that doesn't change anything I said. "*I don't see any calls to register the class, and the API doesn't seem to provide any "register" functions*" - what is the actual API you are working with? Is its documentation available for us to look at? You are declaring your own class, but how are you actually using it in your code?

Comment: @RemyLebeau, it is a rightware product, but I’m don’t think that the documentation is open to view.  I have to log on to see it. The front end graphics part may be doing something, but I don’t know about that. For the backend, we just create a singleton derived class object, and it just magically runs.  The main function is literally a single line where we call getInstance which calls the derived class constructor. The constructor creates some threads and it just runs.

Comment: @brettgrant99 it would still be helpful to see that code. If I had to guess, maybe the base class `Application` constructor is saving its `this` pointer for the API's internal use, so that later code can make virtual method calls via that pointer.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, to be honest, I'm quite embarrassed that I have no idea on how this works, hence my original question.  I see no calls to this class other than the original instantiation.  The main function isn't even a function, it is just a global call to create a singleton instance of the derived class.  I can see that the onUpdate is called about every microsecond, but I can't see where it is called from.  The call stack simply says "external code".  My background is more linux, so I am unsure if this Visual Studio, windows, or APIs in general.

Comment: @brettgrant99 "*I have no idea on how this works*" - I would expect the API's documentation to cover this. "*I see no calls to this class other than the original instantiation*" - which I asked you to show. "*I can see that the onUpdate is called about every microsecond, but I can't see where it is called from*" - it is obviously being calls from inside the API's internals. "*My background is more linux, so I am unsure if this Visual Studio, windows, or APIs in general*" - this is not platform specific behavior. It is obviously something this particular API is doing on your behalf.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - thanks for the help.  I've asked coworkers, and they are also unsure of how it works.  They agree that the API doc is very lacking.  The instantiation is very simple, it is a single line `static MyApp s_Instance` wrapped in a singleton getInstance function that returns a reference to the s_Instance.  I can find no calls to MyApp::getInstance() or uses of the s_Instance variable.  I guess that I need to figure out how Frameworks work now.

Comment: @brettgrant99 this is not general framework behavior. You need to learn how THIS PARTICULAR framework works.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I would love to, but I don't think management will allow that.  I have a hard time accepting that something just "works".  I like to understand why it works.  However, I am not being given the time to figure it out and it is clearly acceptable at this time to leave it.  Seems to be a common business feeling to accept that it works now, and spend thousands to millions figuring it out in the future when it doesn't work, because that will be someone else's problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that original question has been answered as best as it can be given the info that I provided.

The implementation of the framework dictates how this is used.
In my case, the specific framework is hiding a lot of details.
While not common, this is not unheard of and can be considered an anti-pattern, "Call Super"

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

> Why call a Base Class virtual member from an Inherited class?

If you want/need the overriding function to do what the base function does, then it can be useful to call that function instead of duplicating the code. It may even be necessary if that function accesses private state of the base.

> I would have thought that if this is necessary, the documentation would say something like "be sure to call the base class onUpdate function if you choose to write your own".

In cases where it is necessary, the base class documentation should ideally say so.

> Is there a formal name for this implementation?

If you mean "is there a name for this design pattern", there isn't enough details in your question to answer accurately, but based on the names alone, I would guess that this is part of the Observer pattern.